# Is there a way to see the progress status when we submit application to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone

When we upload application from Xcode organizer, after we click the "Submit Application to iTunes Connect" button, is there a way to see the progress percentage?

Answer (score 1):

There is no progress bar, but you can see what they currently do with your application via iTunes Connect.
But those aren't very detailed informations. Just wait and drink tea, it won't speed up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the lack of feedback from the xcode uploader, I just use the Application Uploader utility. See the utility folder in the xcode applications folder.